# What's the difference between Toshiro and Ichigo's Zanpakuto lore?

Tags: bleach

In the series, it's explained that Zangetsu is a part of Ichigo and was suppressing his powers. Since he didn't want Ichigo to become a shinigami, he was practically always hindered Ichigo, as one day he might have to kill him depending on his changes.

Sorry but I read the following part in a wiki. Zangetsu tells Ichigo that the Zanpakuto is physical representation of Ichigo's power, and Ichigo remembers its red ribbon from his friend.

This is where I get a little confused. In one episode, Toshiro and another guy had same dream about the sword and both wielded the sword for a short time. The Soul Society then decided only one can wield him. **However, if the Zanpakuto is a part of a shinigami, then how can two people have same power? And how come Toshiro had dreams about wielding the sword, while Ichigo didn't?** If it wasn't for Rukia power awaking and Urahara forcing through Kido, Ichigo could never have become a shinigami.

It's like Toshiro's Zanpakuto was given to him by Soul Society because they agreed he was worthy of it after beating the other guy.

Comment: something to consider since it seems you havent been reading the manga: http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/%C5%8Cetsu_Nimaiya

Comment: basically the initial sword is a template given by soul society, then your power is added to it to make it unique.

Answer (score 2):

Zangetsu wasn't suppressing Ichigo's powers nor was he hindering Ichigo. Zangetsu only feared that Ichigo would come to him to learn the Final Getsuga Tenshou. Zangetsu didn't want Ichigo to become a Shinigami, because he (and Ichigo) was part Quincy (and not to mention, Hollow as well).

The reason why Toushiro and Soujiro had the same Zanpakuto was explained in the anime. Go watch it.

Ichigo always had the ability to become a Shinigami because he was part Shinigami (from his father). Since his mother was a Quincy, he could have been one too. He could've become a Hollow if he wanted to. Rukia and Urahara only sped up the process.

Comment: "Go watch it" is not an answer here - just explain the reason and mark spoiler block if that's your intention.

Comment: I advised him/her to go watch it so as to receive a full and detailed explanation. I wasn't being rude, I was being considerate.

Comment: You should at least mention the name of the movie *Bleach: The DiamondDust Rebellion* where the explanation was given instead of just anime. Ideally, answers should be self-contained with links and blockquotes where appropriate so that readers don't have to do much, if not any, googling.

Comment: Is that movie canon?? as in is it acknowledged by the writer?